# Qt 5.1.1 installation problem

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qt5

I am new to ubuntu and using 12.04 LTS. I tried to install Qt5.1.1 without software manager. I downloaded the **qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86-offline.run** file and ran it.

It ran smoothly and got a installed in a folder. However when I try to navigate to the `/home/Qt5.1.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin` and execute the *qtcreator executable* from the terminal I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`..it will be really helpful if some one suggested how to correctly install Qt5.1.1 and get rid of this error.